# Reference For Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a good & unquestionably complete reference on solving basic integrals.
Out of all the books in my library I've checked they're all more or less just Thomas calculus with the odd frill attached here & there. The best books I've come across are Piskunov's calculus & a few Indian textbooks on google books but I'm hoping for something better, something more complete & systematic but is more than an integral table with no/few/incomplete/unsystematic methods (i.e. something that would go through the trouble of mentioning that three techniques apply to some integral, systematizing special non-obvious cases etc... ).
To give you an example of what I'm talking about, & why I feel someone will mention a book I haven't come across yet that is my saviour, just pick up every ordinary differential equations book you can & count how many mention first order Abel's Equations of the first or second kind, the Isobaric equation, first order Jacobi & Darboux equations etc... etc... The integral analogue of what I'm looking for would be something like either of 
Murphy, Ordinary Differential Equations and Their Solutions
[http://www.amazon.com/Ordinary-Differential-Equations-Solutions-Mathematics/dp/0486485919/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486485919) or
Zaitsev, Handbook of Exact Solutions for Ordinary Differential Equations
[http://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Solutions-Ordinary-Differential-Equations/dp/1584882972/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584882972)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4418786/442 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4486706/442 and

Answer (score 3):

Note that the last book you reference was written with Polyanin. This last author has a whole [collection](http://www.amazon.com/Andrei-D.-Polyanin/e/B003C153YC) of books of this kind and a very useful website [EqWorld](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/index.htm) allowing to identify your ODE or PDE equation (with Zaitsev and twelve other people in the board)!

One of his books is a 'condensation' of all (from my point of view) : it is the 1500 pages ['Handbook of Mathematics for Engineers and Scientists'](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584885025) (index [here](http://www.crcnetbase.com/doi/book/10.1201/9781420010510)). Of course there is some 'overlay' with your ODE book!

In the board appears too Daniel Zwillinger that produced in 1992 a fine book : ['Handbook of Integration'](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0867202939) that I recommend warmly (he is associated with the G&R tables and has too a book on ODEs). It is a "compilation of the most important methods" in 360 pages.

Should you, after all that, be interested by the 'computer point of view' for indefinite integration (differential algebra : another subject I'll admit...) then there is the [Geddes & all](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0792392590) or the [Bronstein](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540214933).

Comment: Thank you very much, I think Zwillinger is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @FengShuei: I hope you'll like it. It covers many subjects (including path integrals, fractional integration and so on...) but won't necessarily enter into all the details. References are given when necessary to other books like the old [Whittaker & Watson](http://archive.org/details/acoursemodernan00watsgoog) for complex analysis and special functions, [Bender & Orszag](http://books.google.fr/books?id=-yQXwhE6iWMC) for asymptotic methods and others or another book you could appreciate too : the Squire [Integration for engineers and scientists](http://books.google.fr/books?id=WTDvAAAAMAAJ).