# Reference request for practicing integration

Tags: calculus, integration, reference-request

I'm looking for a reference -- of any kind, website or book -- for practicing integration techniques. The only book I have on hand is Stewart's calculus book, but that's not quite what I'm looking for.

I need something with a lot of different types of problems; problems on the challenging side -- in the sense that they involve some clever use of a common technique, or use of a lesser known technique, for example. With that said, I'll most definitely need an accompanying solutions manual.

I have some exposure in analysis at the level of baby Rudin, so more advanced references are welcome as well.

Note:  I did do a  search and found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169360/reference-for-integrals) (Zwillinger), but didn't find much else.

Answer (score 3):

The text you refer to is indeed well worth the cost.  But for the sake of easing the strain on the "pocket-book", I'd suggest the relatively inexpensive books in the Schaum's Outline series: e.g. Calculus, or their [3000 Solved Problems in Calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071635343). Their series of outlines usually serve as a good quick references, but also as a great "work-books" full of exercises and solutions.  You may want to search to see if they have one exclusively with respect to integration.

Comment: I have this one Amy. Good reference.

Comment: @amWhy So if cost wasn't an issue, you would suggest Zwillinger's book?

Comment: Zwillinger's text: Yes, I very much recommend it: as a source for problems, but also as a reference with comprehensive toolkit of a whole array of techniques. And there are classic handbooks in math that come with a much heftier price tag than Zwillinger's. That said, Schaum's Outlines aren't a bad second choice, or additional choice: it's portable (paperback bound), so you they'd both be good to have. Check your local library for Schaum's; the handbook I imagine would only be found at a university/college library...perhaps available via interlibrary loan?

Comment: Let me know your thoughts...With your background, you'd probably get more out of the handbook, but given the meager cost of Schaum's, you could put the skills/techniques you acquire from the handbook to work on some of the problems in Schaum's, at a more recreational level, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

For finding the integration and its techniques good, I have suggested my students to be master in the following book:

> Problems In Calculus Of One Variable by Issak Maron

May be it is an old one respect to what you have been suggested, but I strongly recommend you. Try it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

These international editions also have a ton of practice problems regarding Calculus:
Thomas and Finney Calculus ( I got 9th edition, but there is probably a newer one)
Edwards and Penney Calculus with Analytic geometry

I got these books and I practiced the #%$@ out of them. Still use them for reference once in a while. Truth is though, that Stewart is a pretty good Calc book to study from, but you are right, when it comes to challenge problems, it's limited.