# BOOK RECOMMENDATION: Integration Techniques / Tips

Tags: integration, reference-request, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, book-recommendation

While browsing MSE, I found some posts regarding integration tricks / integration formulae, for both definite and indefinite integrals.

I saw [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942263/really-advanced-techniques-of-integration-definite-or-indefinite?rq=1), [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4099830/what-other-tricks-and-techniques-can-i-use-in-integration?noredirect=1&lq=1), [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70974/lesser-known-integration-tricks?noredirect=1&lq=1), and some other posts.

---

I saw the following (but not only the following),

I am familiar with many of them

Now I am asking about a book that includes such integration formulae with there proofs and examples.

---

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(a+b-x) dx$$

---

For rational expressions of trigonometric functions, substitute:

$$\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}, \tan(x)=\frac{2t}{1-t^2}, \sec(x)=\frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}, \text{and } dx=\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}$$

This is called "tangent half-angle substitution", so these substitutions can be derived by first putting $\tan(x/2)=t$. This substitution also known as "Weierstrass substitution".

---

$$\int_{-a}^{a} f(x) dx = \left\{\begin{matrix}
2\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx &, \text{when }f(x) \text{ is an even function} \\
\\
0 &,  \text{when }f(x) \text{ is an odd function} \\
\end{matrix}\right.$$

---

Integration of an inverse function:

$$\int f^{-1}(x)dx = x f^{-1}(x)-F(f^{-1}(x))+c, \text{where } F(x)=\int f(x)dx$$

---

Frullani Integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(ax)-f(bx)}{x} dx = \bigg(f(\infty)-f(0)\bigg)\log\bigg(\frac{a}{b}\bigg)$$

---

$$\int_{-a}^{a} \frac{f_{1}(x)dx}{1 \pm \bigg(f_{2}(x)\bigg)^{f_{3}(x)}}=\int_{0}^{a}f_{1}(x)dx$$

provided that both $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ are even functions, and $f_{3}$ is an odd function.

---

Laplace Integration:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}ds$$

---

I need a book that includes (not only these) integrals. Hopefully (only one comprehensive) book.

---

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: I’m afraid such an all encompassing book is unavailable..

Comment: @Quanto Hopefully, $\exists$ book $\in \mathcal{U}$niverse.

Comment: As someone who has spent nearly 5 decades of browsing the math collections in dozens of large university libraries, among many other things, I think instead of looking for a comprehensive book on some topic or other (few of which actually exist, and those that do are often treatises intended for research reference purposes), you're better off assembling a collection of fairly comprehensive books on various portions of what you're interested in. That said, I assembled some books on integration techniques in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4418786/13130).

Answer (score 8):

Such books are mostly from more than 50 years ago...  Example

*MacNeish, H. F.*, Algebraic technique of integration, (Publications in Mathematics. 1) Florida: University of Miami Press VIII, 109 p. (1950). [ZBL0041.17803](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0041.17803).

Here is a recent one, about 150 pages:

*Markin, Marat V.*, [**Integration for calculus, analysis, and differential equations. Techniques, examples, and exercises**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/11035), Hackensack, NJ: World Scientific (ISBN 978-981-3272-03-3/hbk; 978-981-3275-15-7/pbk). xii, 164 p. (2019). [ZBL1395.00004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1395.00004).

Advanced methods would be Risch algorithm and similar. (Here the point is not doing it by hand, but programming a computer to do it.) Example:

*Bronstein, Manuel*, Symbolic integration. I: Transcendental functions, Algorithms and Computation in Mathematics. 1. Berlin: Springer. xiii, 299 pp. (1997). [ZBL0880.12005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0880.12005).

Comment: Thanks for the Markin reference, which I didn't know about. I've added it to my answer cited in a comment to the OP's question.